# Netdiscover packages for Fedora?

Tags: fedora, networking, software-rec

Ubuntu has a program called [netdiscover](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/netdiscover).

> Netdiscover is an active/passive address reconnaissance tool, mainly developed for those wireless networks without dhcp server, when you are wardriving. It can be also used on hub/switched networks.
>   Built on top of libnet and libpcap, it can passively detect online hosts, or search for them, by actively sending arp requests, it can also be used to inspect your network arp traffic, or find network addresses using auto scan mode, which will scan for common local networks.

Are there Fedora packages for this or a similar application?

Comment: Did you look in the Fedora repositories? Where else have you looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [someone worked on building it for fedora](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=499951), but stopped working on it sometime in 2009.  I guess there isn't enough interested in bringing it to Fedora.

Comment: The last source rpm posted in that bug is still available and still builds (with `rpmbuild --rebuild`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following link.

www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=netdiscover

However, you will need to manually extract the tarball and compile the source code on fedora to run the application.